# How to make a selector for choosing price

Tags: android, android-custom-view

[image: image of selector]

Both arrow are draggable, and the values will change.
How can I make something like this? What is it called?

Comment: Try SeekBar to doing so

Comment: seek bar is one way , this is 2 way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image that you provided, it looks like you need **SeekBar** which handles can be adjusted from both sides. Default Android SeekBar can only be adjusted from one side.

There is a library that allows you to move handles on both sides of the SeekBar, here is the link to the project page: https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/